# Inner join of two ArrayLists purely in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there a way to do the inner join of two ArrayLists of two different objects based on one field?

Let's say I've got:

```
ArrayList<Car>
ArrayList<Owner>
```

Car would have these attributes: `Weight, Top speed, OwnerId`

Owner would have these attributes: `Name, Age, Id`

The result would be an `ArrayList<Result>` with attributes: `Weight, Top speed, Id, Name, Age`

And I want to make an inner join of these 2 based on a single field called `Id`. Is there any optimal way to do that without using a database or nested loops?

Comment: Join Car and Owner and produce what?

Comment: Are you using Java8?

Comment: Can you share the structure of `Car` and `Owner`? It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do?

Comment: Let's say it could produce another object that I need. `ArrayList<Result>` which would contain fields from both `Car` and `Owner` object.

Comment: one car per one owner or are there communal entities?

Are there duplicates ? Should these be Sets ? Are you getting match for every item from either lists? Are you expecting cars with no owners or owners with no cars??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you:

- use Java 8
- you have `List<Car> cars` and `List<Owner> owners`
- `Result` has a constructor that takes a `Car` and an `Owner`

This is how you can get `List<Result>`:

```
final Map<Integer, Owner> ownersById = owners.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k.id, k -> k));
final List<Result> results = cars.stream()
   .map(car -> new Result(car, ownersById.get(car.OwnerId)))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which:

- creates a `java.util.Map` instance where the key is owner id and the value is the owner instance
- then iterates through the cars and creates `Result` instances, which contain a reference to the car and the owner, which is looked up using the previously created map

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the neatest solution to my question. Though all other answers were really good. Would you mind explaining a little what exactly it does? Or add a reference?

Comment: @OndrejTokar just added a short explaintation

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Collection.retainAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) method.

You have to implement in a special way (see code below) equals method inside your Car and Owner classes.

For example, supposing that both Car and Owner classes have a String id property the code would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    ArrayList<Car> list1 = new ArrayList<Car>();
    list1.add(new Car("ID1"));
    list1.add(new Car("ID2"));
    list1.add(new Car("ID3"));


    ArrayList<Owner> list2 = new ArrayList<Owner>();
    list2.add(new Owner("ID1"));
    list2.add(new Owner("ID3"));
    list2.add(new Owner("ID4"));

    list1.retainAll(list2);
    System.out.println(list1);
}

static class Car
{
    public Car(String id)
    {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        if (obj instanceof Owner)
        {
            Owner other = (Owner) obj;
            if (id == null)
            {
                if (other.id != null)
                    return false;
            }
            else if (!id.equals(other.id))
                return false;
        }
        else if (obj instanceof Car)
        {
            Car other = (Car) obj;
            if (id == null)
            {
                if (other.id != null)
                    return false;
            }
            else if (!id.equals(other.id))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Car [id=" + id + "]";
    }

    public String id;
}

static class Owner
{
    public Owner(String id)
    {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (obj instanceof Owner)
        {
            Owner other = (Owner) obj;
            if (id == null)
            {
                if (other.id != null)
                    return false;
            }
            else if (!id.equals(other.id))
                return false;
        }
        else if (obj instanceof Car)
        {
            Car other = (Car) obj;
            if (id == null)
            {
                if (other.id != null)
                    return false;
            }
            else if (!id.equals(other.id))
                return false;
        }


        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Owner [id=" + id + "]";
    }

    public String id;
}
```

The output will be:

> [Car [id=ID1], Car [id=ID3]]

Obviously in this case you'll have a Car list, if you want another type you can make sure that both classes inherit from the same super class or you can make sure that both classes implements the same interface and than manage that interface type.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the type of `Id` implements `Comparable`:

Firstly, sort the lists, so that the `Id`s are in ascending order:

```
Collections.sort(cars, new Comparator<Car>() {
  @Override public int compare(Car a, Car b) {
    return a.OwnerId.compareTo(b.OwnerId);
  }
});
Collections.sort(owners, new Comparator<Owner>() {
  @Override public int compare(Owner a, Owner b) {
    return a.Id.compareTo(b.Id);
  }
});
```

Then, loop through the elements:

```
int ci = 0, oi = 0;
while (ci < cars.size() && oi < owners.size()) {
```

Walk through the `cars` list looking for a contiguous block where the `Id` field is the same:

```
  Id idStart = cars.get(ci).OwnerId;
  int carStart = ci;
  while (ci < cars.size() && cars.get(ci).OwnerId.equals(idStart)) {
    ++ci;
  }
  List<Car> carsWithId = cars.subList(carStart, ci);
```

Then skip past all of the `Owner` instances with smaller `Id`s:

```
  while (oi < owners.size() && owners.get(oi).Id.compareTo(idStart) < 0) {
    ++oi;
  }
```

Then find the block of `Owner` instances with the same `Id` as the cars:

```
  int ownerStart = oi;
  while (oi < owners.size() && owners.get(oi).Id.equals(idStart)) {
    ++oi;
  }
  List<Owner> ownersWithId = owners.subList(ownerStart, oi);
```

Finally, do something with the car/owner pairs with equal ids:

```
  for (Car car : carsWithId) {
    for (Owner owner : ownersWithId) {
      System.out.println(car + ", " + owner);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible the way you think of it, especially ArrayList can contain only one sort of type (or the subtypes / implementing classes). But it could be a solution for you to use another datastructure that maps the objects by their ids.

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Car, Owner>> map;
```

**Edit:**
The Integer-type in the HashMap could be used to store the id which is the connection between the car and the owner. If you do something like:

```
map.get(10)
```

it will return as HashMap instance, containing one car as a key and one owner as the coresponding value which both should have the id 10. But this is not implicit, you have to take sure of that by creating the Map.

Also, you could write a class that "maps" the inner join:

```
public class CarToOwner() {
     private Car car;
     private Owner owner;
}
```

**Edit:**
If you have a class which contains the car and the owner, it maps directly the relationship between them. You have to take sure either that the id of both types is the same as the connection between them when creating an instance of the CarToOwner-class.

In fact, this is not a really clean solution belonging to some purposes. I would only use this as a "quick and dirty" approach for showing a table in a GUI.

**Edit:**
For cars with multiple owners or owners with multiple cars, it is necessary to store the attributes in lists in CarToOwner or create multiple CarToOwner-instances.

Comment: +1 for the reasonable explanation. Though you could provide more on the HashMap within HashMap, how would that CarToOwner class work?

Comment: what about cars with no / multiple owners?

Comment: I added an edit for multiple cars / owners. To better clarify this, there are missing information about the implementation of car and owner.

Answer (score 1):

First iterate over the `List<Car>` (you should work with the Interface and not the implementation) and add each element in a `Map<Integer, Car>`. (I suppose the ID is unique).

Then iterate over the `List<Owner>` and store the result in `List<Result>`. Of course you will need a constructor for Result that takes a Car and an Owner.

No nested loops here :)

Comment: The reason for using the interface rather than implementation? My model is just attributes, contructor and getters and setters. Does your advice still apply?

Comment: I think this is the best solution so far.

Comment: @OndrejTokar: if you use the Interface you can change the implementation behind it. If you use an ArrayList or an AttributeList or a LinkedList is not important. If you use the Implementation you cannot easily change it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the intersection of the two arrays, you just have to loop on one list and whenever you find an element in the other list that have a matched ID to the current loop element, put it on a third list (the one that you want to hold the intersection elements)

Comment: This means nested loop doesn't it?

Comment: It doesn't have to be if you suggested using a Map.

Comment: exactly, or you can just use list.contains()